# How do I select the calculator buttons with class button to change its class in javascript by using queryselectorAll

Tags: javascript, css, calculator, selectors-api

How do I select the buttons using `queryselectorAll` in my javascript code
to change their theme by applying css?

```html
<html>

    <head>

        <title> 

            calculator 

        </title>

       

<style>

   

    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:wght@700&display=swap');

    h3 u{

        margin-left:85px;

            

        font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;

        

      }

      

     

      .icons{   

        margin-bottom: 300px;

        margin-left: 500px;

      }

     .fa-brands{

       

        margin-left: 10px;

        margin-top:3px;

        font-size: small;

        background-color: black;

        height:25px;

        color:white;

        width:118px;

        border-radius:3px;

        padding-top:5px;

        padding-left:7px;

        cursor:pointer;

        

       

     }

     .fa-solid{

        margin-top:3px;

        font-size: small;

        background-color: black;

        height:25px;

        color:white;

        width:118px;

        border-radius:3px;

        padding-top:5px;

        padding-left:7px;

        cursor:pointer;

        

     }

     

       .container{

                display:flex;

                flex-direction:row;

                width:340px;

                height:540px;

                margin-left: 500px;

                flex-wrap:wrap;

                font-weight:bold;

                background-color: orange;

                border: 3px solid black;

                box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black;

               

                }

           

                .button {

                 height: 70px;

                 width : 70px;

                 margin-top: 5px;

                 margin-right: 5px;

                 font-weight:bold;

                 border: 3px solid black;

                 margin-left:5px;

                 border-radius:10px;

                 cursor: pointer;

                 box-shadow:-1px -1px black;

                }

            .textfield{

                height: 70px;

                width: 320px;

                margin-left:7px;

                border :3px solid black;

                border-radius:10px;

                cursor: pointer;

                box-shadow:-1px -1px black;

                font-size: large;

                font-weight:bold;

                

            

            }

            .equals{

                height: 70px;

                 width : 155px;

            }

          

              .C{

                

                background-color:red ;

                height: 70px;

                width : 70px;

                font-weight:bold;

                margin-left: 5px;

                border :3px solid black;

                border-radius:10px;

                cursor: pointer;

                box-shadow:-1px -1px black;

                

                          }

                          .adjust{

                            margin-left:9px;

                          }

            .darkcontainer{

                background-color: black;

                border: 3px solid white;

            }

            .darkbutton{

              background-color: black;

            }

            .darkbody{

              background-color: black;

            }

            .darkfa-brands{

              border :3px solid white;

            }

            .darkfa-solid{  

              border :3px solid white;  

            }

            .darkh3{

              color:white;

            }

            

                   

</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="orange">

<div class = "container" id="A">

    <h3  id = "h3"><u>CALCULATOR</u></h3>

    

<form>

    <input class = "textfield" type = "text" placeholder="RESULT" name="text" id ="result">

<input class = "C"type = "reset" value = "AC" title=" All Clear">

<button type = "button" class ="adjust button"title="clear" onclick="text.value =text.value.toString().slice(0,-1)" >DE</button>

<button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += '.'">.</button>

<button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += '/'">/</button>

    <button type = "button"  class ="button" onclick="text.value += 1">1</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 2">2</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 3">3</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += '+'">+</button>

    <button type = "button"  class ="button" onclick="text.value += 4">4</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 5">5</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 6">6</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += '-'">-</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 7">7</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 8">8</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 9">9</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += '*'">*</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += '00'">00</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button" onclick="text.value += 0">0</button>

    <button type = "button"   class ="button equals"  onclick="calc()">=</button>  

</form>  

</div>

<div class = "icons">

    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-half-stroke" onclick="change()" id="fas">  Dark mode</i>

    <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"  id = "fab"> <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ayush-sharma-a155a8267"> Linked in</a> </i>

</div>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c803804b72.js" crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>

 <script>

    

 function calc(){

   

    let c = document.getElementById('result').value;

    document.getElementById('result').value=eval(c);

}

function change(){

  let cont = document.getElementById("A");

  cont.classList.toggle("darkcontainer");

  let bo = document.body;

  bo.classList.toggle("darkbody");

  let fas = document.getElementById("fas");

  fas.classList.toggle("darkfa-solid");

  let fab = document.getElementById("fab");

  fab.classList.toggle("darkfa-brands");

  let h3 = document.getElementById("h3");

  h3.classList.toggle("darkh3");

  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

  buttons.classList.toggle("darkbutton")

 

  

}

 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll('button.button')` to get all the buttons with class="button".